# Manifest merger failed Using chaquopy

Tags: flutter-dependencies

This was the error i keep getting showed :

Attribute application@name value=(android.app.Application) from (unknown)
is also present at [:chaquopy] AndroidManifest.xml:9:18-72 value=(com.chaquo.python.android.PyApplication).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:name"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:3:4-33:19 to override.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267347.