# What does add 'tools:replace="android:name"' mean in Gradle build fail?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, chaquopy

I'm trying to following a tutorial (found at https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy) on making a Python file run in a Flutter application using Chaquopy.  I've followed all of the instructions and made any changes for errors that I found answers for over the internet, like adding the Python path/version, changing to the new button types, etc.  I'm now stuck on a new Gradle build fail.  Here is thusere fail:

```
C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\untitled\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:5:9-42 Error:
    Attribute application@name value=(android.app.Application) from AndroidManifest.xml:5:9-42
    is also present at [:chaquopy] AndroidManifest.xml:9:18-72 value=(com.chaquo.python.android.PyApplication).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:name"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-35:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@name value=(android.app.Application) from AndroidManifest.xml:5:9-42
    is also present at [:chaquopy] AndroidManifest.xml:9:18-72 value=(com.chaquo.python.android.PyApplication).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:name"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-35:19 to override.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I already added the line 'tools:replace="android:name"' to the xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.untitled">
    <application
        android:label="untitled"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        android:name="com.chaquo.python.android.PyApplication".
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        tools:replace="android:name"
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When the Python for Windows Modify Setup popup comes up, I've tried just closing it and clicking the Repair button, but I get the same result either way.  I don't understand what the problem is.

I tried adding the line the build fail message suggested and it returned the same error.  I tried moving the location of the suggested line and it still returned the same error.  I also tried cancelling and repairing Python when the popup window came up, but received the same error for both.

Comment: `tools:replace` should be an *attribute* of the `application` tag. Search for examples to see what this looks like.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71183224.